Tell gsc my site has moved before or after upgrade
So either tonight or tomorrow i will be upgrading my free wordpress blog to a paid domain.
I've been told to use google search console to tell google my site has moved to the paid domain.
Never done this before so I'm looking to find out how i should do this.
Should i upgrade my free site and then do the redirect in gsc or do the redirect before i upgrade?
Just worried if i do it after, gsc may not allow me to.

There's no "redirect" in GSC per-se; what you should do is, once the new website is live, you should create a new property in GSC for it and then you use the "Change address" in the previous property.
Make sure to implement the correct/relevant server redirects from the old domain to the new one during this process (Google has a basic guide on site moves, but make sure to be really careful so not to lose any value the old domain already has.
